# US citizens traveling between 2 "no visa required" countries

Tags: visas, us-citizens, ukraine, lithuania

Friends of ours want to come from US to Lithuania then go to Ukraine and back to US (or Ukraine,  then Lithuania). They don't need visas to go to either Lithuania or Ukraine and thinking logically they should be able to fly to Ukraine from Lithuania without any visas.

But logic is not your best adviser in questions like this. What's the best way to verify that this is the case?

Comment: I can't answer specifically for this nationality and set of destinations but as an Australian citizen I move between "no visa required" countries all the time with no problems anticipated and none encountered. I wouldn't expect any in the case of your friends either.

Comment: 'Port of embarkation' - or the country you're flying in from - is usually not concern. What matters is the nationality you hold and whether what visa rules apply to it.

Comment: Well that blew me away, I was certain almost everyone needed a visa + invite for the Ukraine.  But apparently not the US...learn something new every day.

Comment: @Mark Mayo: according to this http://ukraine.visahq.co.uk/ UK citizens don't need Ukrainian visas too (as well as many other countries). Sounds like you are confusing Ukraine with Belarus ;)

Comment: Not at all, that's the website I used to find this fact.  As you see above - 'apparently not the US' - I learnt this after visiting that very site :)  As a NZer we unfortunately DO require visas for both Belarus AND the Ukraine :)

Comment: I thought Ukraine went a lot more liberal with this stuff recently whereas Belarus remained as hardcore as the USSR/Russia )-:

Comment: @Mark Mayo: oh, sorry then. You had London as your location and I made unwarranted assumptions about your citizenship.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't answer specifically about Ukraine or Lithuania, but in many other similar situations I've never had a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you will have no problems flying in and out of these two countries so long as you do not stay over 3 months in either.  They won't care where you've been previously.  I've been in and out of both Ukraine and Lithuania multiple times, though never directly between the two.  I go often between Ukraine and Poland and they never care where I was before. They only care that I haven't overstayed my visa in their own country.  I'm also a US citizen.

Comment: For the EU, the rule is currently a maximum of 90 per visit within the EU zone and not to exceed 180 total per year.  They don't care how frequently you come and go.